# Text editor that supports italic text and tab indenting, via keyboard shortcuts

Tags: applications, 3.0-honeycomb, editing, documents

Background: I've just become to proud new owner of an Asus TF101 honeycomb tablet, which has a nice hardware keyboard attached to it.

I do a lot of writing, and cannot find a text editing app which allows me to set text as italic using CTRL + I, or to reliably indent new paragraphs with the tab key*.

Does anyone here have any recommendations? (I'm pondering writing my own app to do this at the moment, I'm that desperate).

The google docs app doesn't support it (and at any rate doesn't work unless there's an active internet connection). I have tried various free text editing apps, to no avail.
I've asked the developers behind Documents to Go if they support this, but no answer yet. Quickoffice have a feature request for it currently open. Unsure about possible Androffice support, but googling suggest unlikely.

Many thanks in advance,

UPDATE: Documents To Go does not support the CTRL + I shortcut, although italics are supported.

G

PS - I know android tablets are still in their early days, and it might be a case of waiting. The OpenOffice guys have released an ODT *viewer*, hopefully a potential full openoffice android app might do this.

* - the bundled productivity app called Polaris Office supports the tab key for indenting newlines, but not CTRL + I (it requires four screen-touches to turn italics on and off - OK for once in a while, not OK for frequent use)

Comment: I don't believe that viewer is produced by the OOo team, BTW.

Comment: Wow, four screen taps for italic in a text editor? No wonder they needed to be bundled on the device. That said, "Ctrl+I" is actually two screen taps - wouldn't a button near the keyboard that toggles be better?

Comment: @Steve Pomeroy: my tablet comes with a full-size detachable keyboard, so I literally mean the long-standing CTRL + I keyboard shortcut to turn on italics. I'm sure that app developers and OEMs will get there in the end with this, but I was hoping to find something that handles it already.

@eldarerathis - thanks for the info.

Comment: For information, the android 3.2 OTA firmware update has not fixed this issue in the built-in app. HOWEVER, google apparently have offline editing of google docs in their sights for an upcoming release of the docs app, so some hope there.

Comment: Have accepted the answer below, as am conscious that the question has been open for ages.

Comment: FOUND IT! http://hawkiesza.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/new-app-on-android-market-paste/ supports CTRL + I and was written with the transformer in mind, it seems. Very basic, saves as HTML, but precisely what I needed.

Comment: FOUND ANOTHER! OfficeSuitPro does it too. It's a paid app though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents To Go is a very good app. It provides the formatting requirements you wanted and supports creating and reading Microsoft Office documents as well as Google Docs.

It supports word, excel and powerpoint. It can be found on the Android market https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogoapp&feature=search_result

There is a free version but I believe this only let's you view not create or edit documents

Comment: Thanks Boardy.  I did enquire with the dataviz team about keyboard shortcuts, and at present (well, ~2 months ago now I suppose) they don't support CTRL + I for italics, which is really the only thing I need that the bundled office app doesn;t do already. Tablet support, especially tablets with keyboards, is still evolving though - It's probably unrealistic of me to expect this to turn up anytime soon (unless I somehow find the time to go beyond the 'hello world' application and write my own one that does what I want).