# Text App that supports Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ms-office

I'm a writer and i've just gotten a keyboard for my asus transformer (3.2 Honeycomb). However the included polaris office doesn't do keyboard shortcuts like CRTL i (for italics). Anyone know of any text editing app that supports these?

It would be great if it suported docx files but any text editor would do.

Answer (score 1):

try PaSTE, free from the market, as per [Text editor that supports italic text and tab indenting, via keyboard shortcuts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/text-editor-that-supports-italic-text-and-tab-indenting-via-keyboard-shortcuts)

So far the only thing I've found that supports CTRL + I and CTRL + B.

G

Comment: looks like no support for word documents, but it's a nice start!

Comment: Can also confirm that Polaris on the Asus Transformer TF101 with ICS doesn't support CTRL + I (also they've specified their file formats as 'doc 97 to 2003' etc, so no docx either).